# Running more than two web applications on nginx

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

On Ubuntu, I am trying to run three web applications using nginx and uwsgi. I was able to run two applications with following nginx configurations but unsuccessful to run the third one. Please help me how to run it.

First nginx configuration: `air-quality.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/air-quality/socket.sock;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html{
        root /usr/share/nginx.html;
    }
}
```

Without trouble, the above configuration worked out and showed the output on `210.123.33.247:80/airData`.
The second nginx configuration is in `items-rest.conf`. It is:

```
server {
    listen 81;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/items-rest/socket.sock;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html{
    root /usr/share/nginx.html;
    }
}
```

It also showed the intended output on `210.123.33.247:81/items`.
But the third one did not work. The configuration file is:

```
server {
    list en 8090;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    server_name localhost;

    location {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/display_air/socket.sock;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html{
        root /usr/share/nginx.html;
    }
}
```

In an attempt to run the third application, I tried `sudo systemctl reload nginx` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. Then it produced the error saying

> nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/display-air.conf:7

What did I do wrong?  Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a slash here

```
location {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/display_air/socket.sock;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
}
```

Should be

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/display_air/socket.sock;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
}
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake. You are great!  You save me a lot of pain. Thank you, Nisse.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I was able to run the third app. But when I logged in from the web (210.123.33.247:8090), the Internal Server Error occurred. Can you guess why it could happen? When I ran the app independently, i.e., w/o thru neither nginx nor uwsgi, it works fine. That means the program does not have the error, right? What else could be the problem?